# Expression<TDelegate> on EF Include Statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Hello so I am trying to make an some a bit more dynamic, that said i would like to be able to pass in an expression that will include the entities that I am trying to include. when i am trying to do this i keep getting an error that says:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

I have googled this error and saw that they were doing what i can get to work:

```
context.Contacts.Include(contact=>contact.PhoneNumber)
```

what I am trying to do is this:

```
  Func<IEntity, IEntity> func = (contact) => ((Contact)contact).PhoneNumber;
  Expression<Func<IEntity, IEntity>> expression = (contact)=> func(contact);
  context.Contacts.Include(expression);
```

can someone please expain what I am doing wrong and why?

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Contact:IEntity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumberId { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber:IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I have a repository class that looks at the type of class and uses reflection to get the correct DbSet and returns a IQueryable.

```
  public IQueryable Get(IEntity t)
  { 
     var setMethod =  typeof(DbContext)
                          .GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.Set))
                          .MakeGenericMethod(t.getType());
     var query = (IQueryable)setMethod.Invoke(db, null);
     var results = query... 
  }
```

I have a table control that goes and gets the correct data using the typeRepository. So I am trying to be able to include entities to that table.

Comment: `Func`s (and generally delegates and unknown methods) cannot be used inside EF expression trees. Also EF does not like interfaces and casts. Please provide usage scenario - who is passing expression to what, currently it's unclear what are you after.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: It's better, but still unclear what `t` variable is.

Comment: added method signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't have a generic type argument, but simple `Type` parameter, you'd better use the non generic `DbContext` and `IQueryable` services provided by EF.

First, you don't need reflection - `DbContext` provides non generic `Set` method with `Type` argument:

```
public virtual DbSet Set(Type entityType)
```

As for `Include`, you can simply use the non generic `Include` extension method with `string` argument:

```
public static IQueryable Include(this IQueryable source, string path)
```

So the method in question can be implemented like this:

```
IQueryable query = db.Set(t.GetType());
if (t is Contact)
    query = query.Include(nameof(Contact.PhoneNumber));
```

Not the best OOP practices, but works for the chosen design.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your issue relates to the delegate type you are assigning to your Func. IE: `Func<IEntity, IEntity> func`
In which case IEntity does not have a navigation property defined of type IEntity

Try assigning the concrete type for your implementation

```
Func<Contact, PhoneNumber> func
```

Comment: Did you try updating both the Func and Expression to <Contact, PhoneNumer>?
Func<Contact, PhoneNumer> func = (contact) => ((Contact)contact).PhoneNumber;
  Expression<Func<Contact, PhoneNumer>> expression = (contact)=> func(contact);

Comment: yes I did. that still doesn't allow for the generic use of IEntity, and other entities